# How do I set matplotlib plot to "no fill"?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to superimpose one plot over another (they are polygons, really in some lat/lon space, using geopandas, but the plot is simply derived from matplotlib)

I have:

```
figZ, axZ = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(11,8.5))
Sfig = X.plot(ax=axZ, color='white', edgecolor='black', lw=0.7)
Y.plot(ax=axZ, color='white', edgecolor='black', lw=0.7, alpha=0.3)
```

How do I set `Sfig`'s `color` to "no-fill" instead of white? The way it is now it "blurs" my `Sfig` image (`X.plot`) by the alpha of the `Y.plot` one. How do I set "color" to **actually** transparent?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I don't expect upvotes, but this is what I found as solution. I'll vote up better ones if they exist:

```
Sfig = X.plot(ax=axZ, facecolor="none", 
              edgecolor='black', lw=0.7)
```

Comment: "none" is exactly how you specify no color in matplotlib

Comment: I noticed that in windows, I can do `facecolor=''`, but on Linux I have to enter as by the answer `facecolor='none'`

Comment: for latest matplotlib the argument name is `markerfacecolor`

Answer (score 1):

I know this post doesn't mention seaborn, but I suspect a lot of people end up here asking this question for seaborn also (as I did).

The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847586/5299417) almost works for seaborn **boxplots**, you just need to pass it as `boxprops`.

```
sns.boxplot(data=data, x=x, y=y, hue=hue, boxprops=dict(facecolor="none"))
```

**NOTE:** I emphasise that **this solution only works for boxplots**. There is a [more general was of doing this with the new object API](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2492) in seaborn.

Comment: This is not generally true for seaborn and depends on the type of plot you initiate. Depending on the underlying plot structure, you [can often define `edgecolor` and `facecolor`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63894341/8881141) but in some types, [seaborn overrules the user setting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66404883/8881141).

Comment: Ah yes. I just went down a rabbit hole of following github issues around discussing general solutions. I will emphasise that my solution is only relevant to boxplots.

Answer (score 0):

To disable **facecolor** just set with the value **(0, 0, 0, 0)**, i.e.,

```
Sfig = set_facecolor((0,0,0,0))
```