# How to plot unfilled markers in sns.scatterplot with 'hue' set?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have two sets of x-y data, that I'd like to plot as a scatterplot, using `sns.scatterplot`. I want to highlight two different things:

- the difference between different types of data
- the difference between the first and the second set of x-y data

For the first, I'm using the inbuilt `hue` and `style`, for the second, **I'd like to have filled vs. unfilled markers, but I'm wondering how to do so**, without doing it all by hand with `plt.scatter`, where I would have to implement all the *magic* of `sns.scatterplot` by hand.

---

*long version, with MWE:*

I have `X` and `Y` data, and also have some `type` info for each point of data. I.e. I have a sample `1` which is of type `A` and yields `X=11, Y=21` at the first sampling and `X=10, Y=21` at the second sampling. And the same deal for sample `2` of type `A`, sample `3` of type `B` and so on (see example file at the end).

So i want to visualize the differences between two samplings, like so:

```
data = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv', sep=';', index_col=0, header=0)
# data for the csv at the end of the question
sns.scatterplot(x=data['x1'], y=data['y1'])
sns.scatterplot(x=data['x2'], y=data['y2'])
```

[image: plot]

Nice, I can easily see that the first sampling seems to show a linear relationship between `X` and `Y`, whereas the second one shows some differences. Now what interests me, is which `type` of data is affected the most by these differences and that's why I'm using seaborn, instead of pure matplotlib: [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot) has a lot of nice stuff built in, e.g. `hue` (and `style`, to get symbols for printing in b&w):

```
sizes = (200, 200) # to make stuff more visible
sns.scatterplot(x=data['x1'], y=data['y1'], hue=data['type'], style=data['type'],
                size=data['type'], sizes=sizes)
sns.scatterplot(x=data['x2'], y=data['y2'], hue=data['type'], style=data['type'],
                size=data['type'], sizes=sizes)
```

[image: plot2]

OK, so I can easily distinguish my data types, but I lost all information about which sample is what. The obvious solution to me seem to use filled markers for one, and unfilled ones for the other.

However, I can't seem to do that.

I'm aware of this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894341/how-to-get-markers-with-no-fill-from-seaborn-0-11), using `fc='none'` which is not documented in the [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot) documentation but this fails, when also using `hue`:

```
sns.scatterplot(x=data['x1'], y=data['y1'], hue=data['type'], style=data['type'],
                size=data['type'], sizes=sizes)
sns.scatterplot(x=data['x2'], y=data['y2'], hue=data['type'], style=data['type'],
                size=data['type'], sizes=sizes, fc='none')
```

[image: plot3]

As you can see, the second set of markers simply vanishes (there's some artifacts in the `B` data, where hints of a white cross are visible).

I can kinda fix that by setting `ec=...`:

```
sns.scatterplot(x=data['x1'], y=data['y1'], hue=data['type'], style=data['type'],
                size=data['type'], sizes=sizes)
sns.scatterplot(x=data['x2'], y=data['y2'], hue=data['type'], style=data['type'],
                size=data['type'], sizes=sizes, fc='none', 
                ec=('b','b','y','y','y', 'y', 'g', 'g', 'g','r'))
# I would have to define the proper colors, but for this example, they're close enough
```

[image: plot4]

but that obviously has a few issues:

- the markers in the legend aren't fitting anymore, neither color nor fill
- and I'm already halfway in doing-it-all-by-hand territory anyways, e.g. my `ec=` would fail when I want to plot a new dataset with `sample_no` 11.

How can I do that with seaborn? Filled vs. unfilled seems quite an obvious flag for scatterplots, but I can't seem to find it.

---

data  for `testdata.csv`:

```
sample_no;type;x1;y1;x2;y2
1;A;11;21;10;21
2;A;12;22;12;21
3;B;13;23;13.2;22.8
4;B;14;24;13.8;24
5;B;15;25;14.8;25.2
6;B;16;26;16.3;25.9
7;C;17;27;18;28
8;C;18;28;20;26
9;C;19;29;20;30
10;D;20;30;19;28
```

Comment: Short answer: [scatterplot is different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66404883/8881141).